the effect of Schengen visa refusal on Australian visa decision?
I was recently refused for a Schengen visa despite having all my documents prepared.  The refusal reason was:

"The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable".

meanwhile, I have a job offer in Australia and I'm applying for 186 visa for Australia.

Is is mandatory to state that "my visa was refused" during the application? What happens if I don't?

I don't want to lie and declare that. What is the effect of this refusal? Can it end up in refusing my 186 visa?



Does the application include a question asking about prior immigration history? If so, what does it say? What is your citizenship and country of residence? What class of Schengen visa and why was it refused? ‘Having all the documents prepared’ is not a guarantee of success, you need to consider what to address/change to avoid Australian immigration arriving at the same decision.

Please provide more details on your shengen visa refusal. Can you upload an image with personal information blacked out?

Lia, do not alter the question so that already given answers are now no longer fitting the question. Asking about a long term via, as it was is different from asking about all, so mostly short term, visa. So I rolled back your edit.

For temporary visas (e.g., for tourism or business), the most common reason for refusal is that the visa officer doubts your intention to leave the country and return home after the authorized stay.
However, the Australian visa subclass 186 is a permanent resident visa. This means that the usual concern about leaving after the limited authorized period of stay does not apply, as your intent is to stay in Australia permanently. Consequently, past temporary visa refusals generally do not negatively impact applications for permanent or long-term renewable visas.
WITH ONE BIG EXCEPTION: fraud or misrepresentation.
A record of fraud or misrepresentation makes your application fundamentally not credible.
For Schengen visas, "not reliable" is not considered fraud or misrepresentation. It simply means the visa officer has doubts on your honesty, which is different from believing you to be lying.
Going back to your first question:

Is it mandatory to state that "my visa was refused" during the application? What happens if I don't?

If you are asked to declare past visa refusals (Australian permanent visa applications generally do ask for past visa refusals), you must do so. Failing to declare it constitutes fraud and misrepresentation, which is an offense and can lead to a ban from Australia and make your future visa applications much harder (especially to US/Canada/New Zealand/UK). Even if not discovered during your application, misrepresentation can be grounds for canceling your permanent resident status and, if you naturalize, even your Australian citizenship, as they would be based on a false foundation.

@lia A job offer in Australia is only evidence of your intention to leave Greece if you already had the visa allowing you to take up the offer.

@lia what citizenships do you have?

i ask because this answer is definitely not from an australian - and the reality is that the answer is not as simple as this answer suggests

@fabspro The answer above, from an experienced Travel.SE participant, has more weight than your "No, it isn't as simple as that" protest. The SE model invites multiple answers, which users can vote for or against, thus raising the better answers to the top of the list. Instead of sniping from the sidelines, please offer your own answer and see how the community reacts to it.

@fabspro I don't doubt citizenship affects that processing of the visas in general (as a visitor or immigrant): the applicant and the sponsor still need to prove that they are genuine, and some countries (or even regions, e.g. some provinces in China!) do attract greater scrutiny. But a simple refusal (i.e. not for misrepresentation or illegal conducts) of a past temporary visa application to other countries do not in itself constitute a character or negative issue: this does not mean the visa will be approved, just the past Schengen refusal have little if any impact.

@DavidRecallsMonica if you think critiquing an answer is unhelpful, that's a reflecton of your personal views but not a reflection on the utility of criticism generally.

@xngtng i don't think you've understood my point...

@fabspro I would appreciate it if you can make it more explicit what effects the citizenship may have on the impact of a previous negative immigration decision.

@xngtng Your answer does not correctly state the position under australian law and does not cite any reliable sources. However I wanted to try and help you to learn by tailoring an example for you based on your country of citizenship.

@fabspro Your comment is unfortunately still cryptic for me.

@fabspro You are welcome of course to state the correct position. For me it is hard to prove a negative but there is no indication that I can find to say past refusals from other countries on non-character grounds affect the processing of a PR visa.

@xngtng makes sense :)
